# NUnit 3 dynamic ValueSourceAttribute

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have to convert NUnit 2.x tests to NUnit 3.x tests and currently have the situation that there is one base class with tests and `abstract IEnumerable` property used in `ValueSource` for these tests and **many** classes that inherits this base class and overrides this property.
The question is how to convert these tests to NUnit 3.x where `ValueSource` has to be static. Each base child also has different `TestCategory.Subcategory`.

```
[Category(TestCategory.Transformations)]
public abstract class Transformations
{
    [Test]
    public void TransformTest([ValueSource("TestDataSource")] TransformTestSource source)
    {
        // some test logic
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<TransformTestSource> TestDataSource { get; }
}

[TestFixture]
[Category(TestCategory.Transformations)]
[Category(TestCategory.Subcategory.Example1)]
public class ChildExample1
{
    protected override IEnumerable<TransformTestSource> TestDataSource
    {
        get { /* get data for example from database, or file */ }
    }
}
```

The only way in my mind is to remove abstract property definition from abstract class and define this property in each child class but it sounds awful. Is there a better way?

**EDIT:** Sometimes, there are also some other tests in child class, so those classes are there not always only for data fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class must be abstract else NUnit will instantiate it and run the tests it contains. Of course it will also re-run the same tests when it instantiates the base class. This is at best confusing and at worst will give errors when the tests are run on the base class alone.

You use the term **dynamic** in the question without explanation. If what you mean by that is an **instance** method or property, then this answer is for you. Of course, the contrary of a static method is an instance method in C# and "dynamic" is something else. In any case, if you do mean something else, please edit your question to explain.

So... while NUnit 3 requires your source to be static, that doesn't limit you to only using things that are known at compile time. If your source is a static **method** rather than a field, then it's possible for you to discover the necessary information to generate the data (in some sense) "dynamically."

It is also possible in NUnit 3 to use `TestCaseSource` to contain your data. In that case, Form 3 of the attribute constructor (see the docs) does allow use of an instance member. This form, however, puts your data in a separate class from your tests and may not suit your usage.

Comment: My question is what I can do with the **TestDataSource** since it has to be `static` now. I can create the same static property in every subclass, but it lacks the *required bond* of abstract+override since `static` can not be `abstract`. It is not good design so there must be better way how I can do that. I am also not sure if it is OK to have static property in base abstract class, because it is then shared for all subclasses - for all tests. Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: As the docs indicate, Form 3 of TestCaseSource uses an instant member. However, this would need to be a class with default constructor entirely separate from your test hierarchy so I can see it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: There are similar tests in NUnit itself, which simply defines the source separately in each derived class. See, for example, https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/tests/Constraints/EqualConstraintTests.cs where `EqualConstraintTest` derives from `ConstraintTestBase`. I wasn't able to find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution using the `TestCaseSource` with a method name and a manual implementation that works in a similar way as Form 3 of `TestCaseSource`.

I made the base class abstract and gave it a generic parameter.  This generic parameter is used to indicate the class that generates the test cases (similar to Form 3 of `TestCaseSource`).

I add a static method that generates the test cases based on the generic type parameter.  This static method is then used as the test case source.  In each sub class I can then add a custom class to generate its test cases.

The base class is as follows then:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class BaseTest<TCases>
  where TCases : IEnumerable, new()
{
  public static IEnumerable TestCases()
  {
    TCases t = new();
    foreach (object o in t)
    {
      yield return o;
    }
  }

  [Test]
  [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCases))]
  public void TestACase(int? case)
  {
    Assert.That(case, Is.Not.Null);
  }  
}
```

Then in the derived class, I define an inner class that generates the test cases, as follows.

```
public class Derived
  : BaseTest<Derived.MyCases>
{
  public class MyCases : IEnumerable
  {
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
      yield return 5;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution seems to work just fine and I'm quite pleased with it.

In the example I use `TestCaseSource`, but you should be able to use the same technique with `ValueSource`.